# Put a point on ggplot irrespective of the dataframe

Tags: r

I have a below plot in ggplot. The plot is getting data from dataframe asd. Is there a way to put a point (3.2, 7) on the plot. I mean x-axis is 3.2 and y-axis is 7. This point is irrespective of the dataframe asd

```
asd <- data.frame(x_axis = c(1,2,3), y_axis = c(6,8,9), c = c("a","a","a"))
p <- ggplot(asd, aes(x=x_axis, y=y_axis)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = c)) + xlab("") + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
ggplotly(p)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just add another `geom`:

```
+ geom_point(x = 3.2, y = 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ggplot(asd, aes(x=x_axis, y=y_axis)) +
 geom_line(aes(colour = c)) + 
 geom_point(aes(x = 3.2, y = 7)) +
 xlab("") + 
 theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
```

[image]